# angular 14 ssr deployment on azure, responding html in rsponse

Tags: angular, azure, angular14

I am deploying `angular 14 with ssr`  in Azure web app. I have **`two folders in dist browser server`** path to browser folder for front end, how to use server folder, what i have done now is used web.config file in browser folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <add fileExtension=".svg" allowed="true" />
                    <add fileExtension=".woff" allowed="true" />
                    <add fileExtension=".woff2" allowed="true" />
                </fileExtensions>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
  
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <!-- <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="no-sniff"/>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN"/>
        <add name="X-Xss-Protection" value="1; mode=block"/>
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"/> -->
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="" />
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Now i am getting html in response, Api calls are 200...

I want to get proper response, on local all is fine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To use server folder for server-side rendering, you need to create a web.config file in the server folder. The web.config file should contain the rewrite rules for the server-side rendering. Refer below:-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This web.config file will route all requests to the **`server.js file`** in the server folder. You can modify the file path in the path attribute of the add element to match the name of your server-side rendering file. Also, make sure that you have installed the **`iisnode module`** in your **Azure Web App**.

*I tried deploying one sample Angular app with sample API, Here are my files:-*

**Created a new Angular app with ssr:-**

```bash
ng new my-ssr-app
cd my-ssr-app
```

```bash
npm install json-server --save
```

**Created sample db.json:-**

```json
{
  "data": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Item 1" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Item 2" }
  ]
}
```

**My package.json:-**

```json
{
  "name": "my-ssr-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": " npm run start:api",
    "start:api": "json-server --watch db.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "json-server": "^0.17.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

**Created one service API :-**

```bash
ng generate service api
```

**api.service.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-ssr-app';
}
```

**Generated component list like below:-**

```bash
ng generate component item-list
```

**item-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-list',
  templateUrl: './item-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-list.component.css']
})
export class ItemListComponent implements OnInit {
  items: any[];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.getItems().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.items = data;
    });
  }
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ItemListComponent } from './item-list/item-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'items', component: ItemListComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/items', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Local Output:-

[image]

***While deploying the angular app make sure to build the Angular app locally with ng build and then Deploy the dist folder to the Web app and not the complete folder:-***

[image]

[image]

**After deployment:-**

Make sure you have index.html in the Default Documents:-

[image]

Make sure you have added the path to **`site\wwwroot\<your-app-name-from-package.json-file>`**

[image]

**Sample Angular SSR app running successfully like below:-**

[image]

Additionally check the Diagnose and Solve Problems tab in your Azure Web app for more insights.

Comment: when i create build, i never got server.js file  in root, i got server.ts file, plz explain this one, and i tried  "npm run build:ssr"  command for deployment build.

Comment: and i am working in Angular 14

Comment: you share wrong code for "api.service.ts" file

Comment: and you are deploying simple angular, i am asking about angular ssr...

Comment: Did you try deploying your angular dist folder only to your Web app? As, Its mandatory to deploy dist folder in Azure web app for the Angular app to load

Comment: I'll recehck my files again

Comment: yes i am deploying dist folder, dist has another folder and then in that folder i have two folders, browser and server....
browser is having web.config file, i am using this file and and out of browser folder according to my path, but server is not accessible